# Regex $1 into variable interferes with another variable

Tags: regex, perl

I have been struggling with a section of my code for a while now and can't figure it out. Seems to have something to do with how $1 is handled but I cannot find anything relevant.

The regex finds the 16640021 and assigns it to a position in the arrays.

```
my @one;
my @two;
my $articleregex = qr/\s*\d*\/\s*\d*\|\s*(.*?)\|/p; # $1 = article number
my $row = "   7/  1|        16640021|Taats 3 IP10                       |14-03-03|        |    |        1,0000|st |   | 01|    | N|  0|";

    if ($row =~ /$articleregex/g) {
        $one[0] = $1; 
    }
    if ($row =~ /$articleregex/g) { 
        $two[0] = $1;
    }
print $one[0];
print $two[0];
```

Which outputs

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at perltest3.pl line 13.
16640021
```

It appears that the designation of $one[0] somehow interferes with that of $two[0]. This seems strange to me as the two variables and their designations should not be interacting in any way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you used `if (//g)` instead of `if (//)`.

- `//g` in scalar context sets `pos($_)`<sup>[1]</sup> to where the match left off, or unsets `pos($_)`<sup>[1]</sup> if the match was unsuccessful<sup>[2]</sup>.
- `//g` in scalar context starts matching at position `pos($_)`<sup>[1]</sup>.

For example,

```
$_ = "ab";
say /(.)/g ? $1 : "no match";  # a
say /(.)/g ? $1 : "no match";  # b
say /(.)/g ? $1 : "no match";  # no match
say /(.)/g ? $1 : "no match";  # a
```

This allows the following to iterate through the matches:

```
while (/(.)/g) {
   say $1;
}
```

Don't use `if (//g)`<sup>[3]</sup>!

---

1. `$_` is being used to represent the variable being matched against.
2. Unless `/c` is also used.
3. Unless you're unrolling a `while (//g)`, or unless you're using `if (//gc)` to tokenize.